# Apache seems to break when listening on multiple port/IP combinations

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

**EDIT: To clarify a bit, I am running Apache 2.2.11**

I'm setting up a development server which would only listen on a specific port/IP `10.0.10.4:80`.  But I potentially see issues with my current configuration of my live server as it listens on all IP's.  These are two separate Apache instances with their own httpd.conf file.

I currently have my live apache instance listening on all IP's for 3 specific ports, Ex:

```
Listen *:8081
NameVirtualHost *:8081
Listen *:8080
NameVirtualHost *:8080
Listen *:80
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

I have multiple Virtual hosts running on my live server with definitions of:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081></VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080></VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80></VirtualHost>
```

I would like to restrict the IPs for the live server to 3 IPs and 3 ports (9 total) so that there is not chance the live server could be served when trying to request the development server.  The live server listens on 3 IPs for redundancy.  NAT translates the public IP to one of the three.

```
10.0.10.1:8081
10.0.10.1:8080
10.0.10.1:80
10.0.10.2:8081
10.0.10.2:8080
10.0.10.2:80
10.0.10.3:8081
10.0.10.3:8080
10.0.10.31:80
```

The reason the two servers are running as separate Apache instances is so that I can start/stop/reset/crash them independently.

When I set the live server to use the combination of IPs/Ports with their own `Listen` and `NameVirtualHost` lines the Apache instance with not start up again.  I've read that the  declaration has to match the NameVirtualHost value, but I tried to lists multiple IP/Port pairs in the  declaration with no luck.  However, I forget if the Apache instance started up but didn't display the sites, or if it didn't start up at all (I'd rather not take down the live sites again in the middle of the day to find out).

Comment: `NameVirtualHost` is dead since 2.3. Seems you can't use masks in `Listen`. rtm. `Listen 8080` or `Listen 10.0.10.31:8080`

Comment: So `NameVirtualHost` is dead and I can't use it.  What are you saying about `Listen`?  I don't know what you mean by `rtm`.  Are you saying I cannot use `Listen` as you use in your examples?  How should I use them?  Can I exclude both `Listen` and `NameVirtualHost`?

Comment: `Listen 8081`, `Listen 8080`, `Listen 80` and 9 VirtualHosts like `<VirtualHost 10.0.10.1:8081>ServerName domain.com</VirtualHost>` or 3 like `<VirtualHost 10.0.10.1:8081 10.0.10.2:8081 10.0.10.3:8080>ServerName domain.com</VirtualHost>`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the router NATs the public IP to any one of the three - you can try [Mixed port-based and ip-based virtual hosts configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#ipport) for your live server and also for your development server. 
 Good Luck!